# Create a new NsmutableArray in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

Hello I am newbie to ios and objective c. I am working on a demo. In that I am having a for loop for adding values to `NSMutableArray`. Now this array will be added to `NSMutableDictionary`. Now inside this for loop i am having an if condition for checking string. I am adding objects to the array in "if" part and want to create a new Array when condition fail. I have tried as below, but in my Dictionary only one array saved. Can anyone help me where i have made mistake?

```
NSMutableArray *listingCommonArr,sectionTitles,eventDate;

int j=0;
NSString *dt;
NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sectionTitles = [orderedSet array];

    NSLog(@"===listing common array---%d",[listingCommonArr count]);

    sectionData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    for(int i =0;i<[listingCommonArr count];i++)
    {

         dt = [[listingCommonArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"start_date"];

        NSLog(@"====my date at place===%@ & my date is====%@",[sectionTitles objectAtIndex:j],dt);
        for (int i =0; i < [listingCommonArr count]; i++) {
            dt = [[listingCommonArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"start_date"];

            if ([(NSString *)[sectionTitles objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:dt]) {
                [sectionArray addObject:listingCommonArr[i]];
                //sectionData = @{dt : sectionArray}; // <-- PAY ATTENTION ON THIS LINE, PLEASE

                //[sectionData setValue:sectionArray forKey:dt];

                sectionData = [@{dt : sectionArray} mutableCopy];

            } else {
                [sectionData setObject:@"New value" forKey:@"string"];
                sectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                j++;
            }
        }
    NSLog(@"====my section DAta is==%@",sectionData);
    }
```

**errorTrace**

```
-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc6547832a0
2015-12-18 19:39:41.387 iPhoneExploreCayman[41719:13822557] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc6547832a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a551c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a1e8bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a5590ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4af13c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4aecd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   iPhoneExploreCayman                 0x000000010604a48c -[iPhoneECListingView GetEventListingData:] + 1884
    6   iPhoneExploreCayman                 0x000000010605644b -[iPhoneECListingView EventListStart] + 1323
    7   iPhoneExploreCayman                 0x0000000106055a98 -[iPhoneECListingView EventClicked:] + 2312
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000108832d62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010894450a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001089438d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010887f958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000108880282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000108846541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
```

Comment: I am wondering why your app is not getting crash while you are accessing  'listingCommonArr' which is not initialised with any object. You are writing 'eventDate =[listingCommonArr  valueForKey: @"start_date"];' which is not possible because 'listingCommonArr' is a mutable array not a dictionary.

Comment: `sectionData = @{dt : sectionArray};` is supposed to be `sectionData = [@{dt : sectionArray} mutableCopy];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm highly confused about what you actually want to do here, but... after your comments I have completely updated my answer removing the previous assumptions about what actually is supposed to happen.

it seems to me you want(ed) to group a series of *words* by the first letter. you have posted a list of animals as example, so I worked with those.

you defined the expected output:

```
NSDictionary *_expectedOutput = @{@"A" :@[@"Affrican cat", @"Assian cat", @"Alsesian fox"], @"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"], @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"], @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"], @"E" : @[@"Emu"], @"R" : @[@"Rhinoceros"], @"S" : @[@"Seagull"], @"T" : @[@"Tasmania Devil"], @"W" : @[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"]};
```

as you can see my *input* array is just an unsorted list of random names of animals from your sample *output*:

```
NSArray *_input = @[@"Whale Shark", @"Tasmania Devil", @"Affrican cat", @"Bear", @"Seagull", @"Black Swan", @"Whale", @"Wombat", @"Camel", @"Rhinoceros", @"Cockatoo", @"Buffalo", @"Assian cat", @"Alsesian fox", @"Emu"];
```

I'm working with that *input* array and I am going to group them by their first letter and build up the *output*:

```
NSMutableDictionary *_output = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[[_input sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSString *_firstLetter = (obj.length > 0 ? [obj substringToIndex:1] : nil);
    if (_firstLetter) {
        NSMutableArray *_list = [_output valueForKey:_firstLetter];
        if (_list == nil) {
            _list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:obj];
            [_output setValue:_list forKey:_firstLetter];
        } else {
            [_list addObject:obj];
        }
    }
}];
```

that is pretty much it, if you'd log the `_output`, you can see on the console that is identical to your `_expectedOutput` collection.

Comment: Hello ,I want to add arrays in dictionary like this. `@"A" :@[@"Affrican cat", @"Assian cat", @"Alsesian fox"],
                @"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
                @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
                @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
                @"E" : @[@"Emu"],
               @"R" : @[@"Rhinoceros"],
                @"S" : @[@"Seagull"],
                @"T" : @[@"Tasmania Devil"],
                @"W" : @[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"]};`

Comment: Now hope you got what i want,date wise arrays into a dictionary.

Comment: Crash is not solved by your code and also dictionary removes previous array in else condition.I have updated code in question please see.

Comment: @JIGAR, I encourage you to delete your entire current code and start over from scratch – your current code definitely will not give you anything like you'd expect. ever. I will update my answer soon with the proper solution.

Comment: @JIGAR, just curiosity, what is your input array? the name of the animals?

Comment: No...Its an example,The way i want to add arrays in Nsdictionary

Comment: @JIGAR, okay, I have worked out the grouping algorithm for your sample collection, but it works with anything else, as long as the _input_ array contains the string items, and it groups them by their first letter.

Comment: @JIGAR, well, if your _input_ different or if you expected _different_ output, obviously you will need a _different_ algorithm... that is why I asked you about what is the input and output collection, if you don't tell that but send an _example_ I can create solution for only the _example_, not for your real problem. I'm not a mind reader to see what you _input_ array is, or what the grouping condition is.

Comment: I just want to group the objects in seperate arrays by comparing the dates in array objects,and add these all arrays to an Nddictionary.

Comment: yep,thing is i have not simple array,its an array of objects...by using this array i have to create other arrays comparing to date and after that i want too add them to dictionary,.

Comment: @JIGAR, okay, if you think you can use my answer to develop your final solution, please accept this answer – if you can't, you have to specify exactly the _input_ and expected _output_, otherwise your question cannot be answered based on _examples_, because your code is a big mess, no one understand actually what you want (I still don't have any clue either about which problem you are still facing as my answer is a very clear and working solution), so you must be more specific in your OP  if that answer does not help on you.

Answer (score 0):

you have sectionData = @{dt : sectionArray}; outside of the if section.
So on each iteration you dictionary will be recreated.

As I think you need the Mutable dictionary for sectionData, and move that string under "else" section

1 initialize mutable dictionary somewhere before the loop:

```
sectionData = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

2 adding current array to dictionary must be under "else" block, also as I understand, you should create new sectionArray:

```
else
{
  [sectionData setObject: sectionArray forKey:dt];
  sectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Comment: But what code change should i make ?can you suggest me please?

Comment: I've extend my responce

Comment: i have edited my code as per your suggestion now it fires an eroor in else condtiion

Comment: can you also update the source code in your question?

Comment: sure...pls wait i am just uodate u

Comment: remove all occurrencies of "sectionData = @{dt : sectionArray};" this code replace mutable dictionary with non mutable dictionary. Also "[sectionData setObject:@"New value" forKey:@"string"];" it was exception, in your case itt will be something like "[sectionData setObject: sectionArray forKey:dt];"

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `sectionData = @{dt : sectionArray};` or anything `sectionData` is set other values are remove from dictionary and only last pair stays.(you are initializing dictionary every time you call `setObject: forKey:`)

If you want to create mutable dictionary and add objects to it you should do:

```
NSMutableDictionary *d2 = [NSMutableDictionary new];//sectionData in your case

[d2 addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"b":@"c"}];//new key value pair added to d2

[d2 addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"c":@"d"}];//new key value pair added to d2

[d2 addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"d":@"e"}];//new key value pair added to d2
```

Comment: What to do when data comes dynamic,You stated static way that i already know buddy\